# Google couldn't verify your identity

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-app-verification

I opened my Google Play Console account and paid 25 dollars. I uploaded my ID card to verify my account but it didn't verify my account. I don't understand how it can't verify it when I have real documents picture uploaded. How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: I would be contacting Google.

Comment: How to contact google regarding this issue ?

Comment: Well, not from a Programming Stack...